# Converting Cursor into generic object android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, generics, cursor

I'm implementing some funcions on SQLite for Android so I can use them for generic objects.
I'm having some troubles with the "SelectAll" method. I can query my object into a cursor, having only the class of it.
I'm doing this:

```
public ArrayList<?> SelectAll(Class<?> foo){
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("select all from ?", new String[]{foo.getSimpleName()});
    ArrayList<?> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Field[] fields = foo.getFields();
    try {
        Constructor<?> constructor = foo.getConstructor(foo);
        // list.add(constructor.newInstance(  ));
    }catch(Exception ex){
        return list;
    }
    return null;
}
```

My problem is in the commented line. I have the array of all parameters got with the getFields. But now i don't know how to cycle them for filling my object.
Anyone can help me? I need to cycle the cursor way to fill my ArrayList with foo items.

PS: This method must be generic. Not specific, so I have to get property from my Field[] and not directly hard-coding.

Thanks all in advice, any help will be appreciated.

ADD_1:

Since this method is in a "generic class" implemented by every class which uses those method, what about creating it like

```
public class<T> foo{
    public <T> ArrayList<T> SelectAll(){
        //no more need class, but work with "this" world
    ...
    }
}
```

and working with this instead of calling everytimes the class? is it possible?
I will call this like

```
ArrayList<Foo> foo = new Foo().SelectAll();
```

It should work fine right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a generic type parameter instead of a wildcard will fix the problem:

```
public <T> ArrayList<T> SelectAll(Class<T> foo){
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("select all from ?", new String[]{foo.getSimpleName()});
    ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Field[] fields = foo.getFields();
    try {
        Constructor<T> constructor = foo.getConstructor(foo);
        list.add(constructor.newInstance(  ));
    }catch(Exception ex){
        return list;
    }
    return null;
}
```

The problem with your original code is that the wildcard (`?`) type in Java is special -- the generic type `T` refers to some unknown type that is nonetheless the same everywhere its used in the method, but `?` refers to a *different* unknown type everywhere.

So what your original function was saying was:

- create a list containing objects of some unknown type `?_1` (on the third line of your program)
- then instantiate an object using a constructor of type `?_2` (on line 6)
- try to put the object of type `?_2` into the list of type `?_1`.

Since `?_1` and `?_2` aren't connected in any way, the typechecker rightly rejects the program. (For instance, what if `?_1` is `Integer` and `?_2` is `String`?)

My version fixes the issue by simply telling the compiler that while we don't know what type we're talking about, know that it's the *same* unknown type everywhere. That lets the typechecker know that whatever type the constructor produces is the same type that the list accepts.

Comment: So between T and ? is better to use T for performances, because ? istantiate every time a different object, even if they are equals, right? I'll improve a last question on my post, if you ave time answer this question please, anyway this is the solution. thanks! :)

Comment: Actually, there's no performance implication to using `?` over `T` or vice versa. These annotations are only used by the type checker; they're completely ignored at runtime.